# Request for member Name in something not a structure or Union

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to call the webservices in my app and while checking it in console it's showing the number of objects (i am using a mutable array), and then while trying to display the name of the objects (here the object is `location`), it's giving me an error in this line:

```
for (SDZArrayOfLocationWithLatestGrades* location in a) {

NSLog(@" - %@", location.Name); // error here and a is the mutable array

}
```

Here's the class SDZArrayOfLocationWithLatestGrades

@implementation SDZArrayOfLocationWithLatestGrades

```
+ (id) newWithNode: (CXMLNode*) node
{
    return [[[SDZArrayOfLocationWithLatestGrades alloc] initWithNode: node] autorelease];
}

- (id) initWithNode: (CXMLNode*) node
{
    if(self = [self init]) {
        for(CXMLElement* child in [node children])
        {
            SDZLocationWithLatestGrades* value = [[SDZLocationWithLatestGrades newWithNode: child] object];
            if(value != nil) {
                [self addObject: value];
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}

+ (NSMutableString*) serialize: (NSArray*) array
{
    NSMutableString* s = [NSMutableString string];
    for(id item in array) {
        [s appendString: [item serialize: @"LocationWithLatestGrades"]];
    }
    return s;
}
```

@end

Comment: What is `SDZArrayOfLocationWithLatestGrades` and how is it defined? Why would a variable of that type be named "location"?

Comment: Did you import the header for SDZ....? Is it really .Name? By naming conventions it should be .name.

Comment: @Chuck: This is a Class and is imported in the current class. location is because the web service when passed the params, return the location. @ Eiko: It's imported and i tried both .name and .Name

Comment: Can you show the header file for SDZ...?

Comment: That's one hell of a class name...

Comment: @Eiko: Updated the question with SDZ class

Comment: @Ashutosh: That's the implementation - the header file it the .h file. And I cannot see any hint for a name property here.

Answer (score 1):

In your first line `SDZArrayOfLocationWithLatestGrades` implies that your location object is an array, which of course doesn't have a `Name` property. I suspect you mean something else.

Comment: So what should i do to return the name of the locations

Comment: What is "a"? Is it the mutable array you were talking about? If so, what is it an array of, an array of arrays? Or is it supposed to be an array of objects? If an array of objects, what kind of objects?

Comment: 'a' is an mutable array. And it should contain the name of the places.

Comment: So each object in `a` is simply an NSString with the name? If so then `NSLog(@" - %@", location);` should log the description of `location`, which should simply be its string contents, the name.

Answer (score 1):

The dot syntax, the way you are using it at least (ie .Name) is either 1) C code for accessing variables within a C structure or a C union. Make sure that the contents of the array a are C structures (or unions) which have a property called Name, or 2) Objective-C code for accessing synthesized properties of instances of classes.

That's why the other guys are asking for the definition of SDZArrayOfLocationWithLatestGrades, it needs to have a property called Name.

Inferring from the name of the variable (SDZArrayOfLocationWithLatestGrades), it sounds like this is an array. If SDZArrayOfLocationWithLatestGrades is the array which contains the structs with property Name, then you are using the fast enumeration stuff wrong.

```
for (SDZArrayOfLocationWithLatestGrades* location in a)
```

In the above you are saying that the variables which reside inside a are of type SDZArrayOfLocationWithLatestGrades*, which is probably wrong (unless you are storing arrays inside arrays). You need to replace SDZArrayOfLocationWithLatestGrades* with the variable type which you are storing inside the array a.

Bad explanation... but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Well actually... if `SDZArrayOfLocationWithLatestGrades` was a class that had a synthesized `Name` property, `a` was an array of those objects, and you fast enumerated through them that way, location.Name would be a valid reference to that property. There's nothing about this code that indicates or implies that the `.Name` reference is in reference to a struct or union.

Comment: @Matthew Yeah you are completely right. The dot syntax is also used for accessing instance properties. I was focusing the answer on what was the likely cause of the error for the OP (wrong type specification in the fast enum). I've edited the answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that the `SDZArrayOfLocationWithLatestGrades` class has a `Name` property. This is why you can't access it. Perhaps you meant to use the type of the objects *contained in* the SDZArrayOfLocationWithLatestGrades?